# Ler JSON e transformar em lista em Java

Tags: java, json

Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
{
    "_status": "sucesso",
    "_dados": [
        {
            "IdIntegracao": "H1xo7lOOX",
            "SacadoCPFCNPJ": "08896903912",
            "SacadoEmail": "lehcustodiofs@gmail.com",
            "SacadoEnderecoNumero": "228",
            "SacadoEnderecoBairro": "SANTA MARIA",
            "SacadoEnderecoCEP": "87970000",
            "SacadoEnderecoCidade": "NOVA LONDRINA",
            "SacadoEnderecoComplemento": "casa",
            "SacadoEnderecoLogradouro": "RUA BELO HORIZONTE,228",
            "SacadoEnderecoPais": "Brasil",
            "SacadoEnderecoUF": "PR",
            "SacadoNome": "LEANDRO SANTOS CUSTODIO",
            "SacadoTelefone": null,
            "TituloDataDesconto": "13/10/2018 00:00:00",
            "TituloDataDesconto2": null,
            "TituloDataEmissao": "13/09/2018 00:00:00",
            "TituloDataVencimento": "13/10/2018 00:00:00",
            "TituloDataMulta": "14/10/2018 00:00:00",
            "PagamentoData": "13/09/2018 00:00:00",
            "PagamentoDataCredito": "14/09/2018 00:00:00",
            "TituloPrazoProtesto": null,
            "TituloMensagem01": "Infomania Sistemas Empresariais",
            "TituloMensagem02": "Após vencimento multa de 0,03 e juros de 0,50.",
            "TituloMensagem03": "Obrigado pela preferência.",
            "TituloMensagem04": null,
            "TituloMensagem05": null,
            "TituloMensagem06": null,
            "TituloMensagem07": null,
            "TituloMensagem08": null,
            "TituloMensagem09": null,
            "TituloInstrucao1": null,
            "TituloInstrucao2": null,
            "TituloOcorrencias": [
                {
                    "codigo": "02",
                    "mensagem": "Movimento: Entrada confirmada",
                    "criado": "2018-09-14T13:34:09.000Z",
                    "atualizado": "2018-09-14T13:34:09.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "codigo": "06",
                    "mensagem": "Movimento: Liquidação Normal",
                    "criado": "2018-09-14T13:34:09.000Z",
                    "atualizado": "2018-09-14T13:34:09.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "codigo": "28",
                    "mensagem": "Movimento: Tarifa",
                    "criado": "2018-09-14T13:34:09.000Z",
                    "atualizado": "2018-09-14T13:34:09.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "codigo": "B3",
                    "mensagem": "Tarifa de registro de entrada do título",
                    "criado": "2018-09-14T13:34:09.000Z",
                    "atualizado": "2018-09-14T13:34:09.000Z"
                }
            ],
            "TituloMovimentos": [
                {
                    "codigo": "02",
                    "mensagem": "Movimento: Entrada confirmada",
                    "data": "13/09/2018 00:00:00",
                    "ocorrencias": []
                },
                {
                    "codigo": "06",
                    "mensagem": "Movimento: Liquidação Normal",
                    "data": "13/09/2018 00:00:00",
                    "ocorrencias": [
                        {
                            "codigo": "H5"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "codigo": "28",
                    "mensagem": "Movimento: Tarifa",
                    "data": "13/09/2018 00:00:00",
                    "ocorrencias": [
                        {
                            "codigo": "B3",
                            "mensagem": "Tarifa de registro de entrada do título"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "TituloNossoNumero": "2844",
            "TituloNumeroDocumento": "2844",
            "TituloOrigemDocumento": null,
            "PagamentoRealizado": true,
            "TituloValorJuros": "0,50",
            "PagamentoValorCredito": "0,00",
            "TituloValorDesconto": "0,00",
            "TituloValorDescontoTaxa": "0,00",
            "TituloValorDescontoTaxa2": "0,00",
            "TituloValorOutrosAcrescimos": "0,00",
            "TituloValorMulta": "0,00",
            "TituloValorMultaTaxa": "0,00",
            "PagamentoValorPago": "3,00",
            "PagamentoValorTaxaCobranca": "1,50",
            "TituloValorAbatimento": "0,00",
            "PagamentoValorOutrasDespesas": "0,00",
            "PagamentoValorIOF": "0,00",
            "PagamentoValorOutrosCreditos": "0,00",
            "PagamentoDataTaxaBancaria": "13/09/2018 00:00:00",
            "TituloValor": "3,00",
            "situacao": "LIQUIDADO",
            "impressao_visualizada": false,
            "motivo": null,
            "PagamentoValorDesconto": "0,00",
            "PagamentoValorAcrescimos": "0,00",
            "PagamentoValorAbatimento": "0,00",
            "TituloAgenciaCobradora": null,
            "TituloAgenciaCobradoraDv": null,
            "TituloDataDocumento": null,
            "TituloLinhaDigitavel": "74891.11828 02844.307286 04612.331035 6 76760000000300",
            "TituloNossoNumeroImpressao": "182028443",
            "TituloCodigoBarras": "74896767600000003001118202844307280461233103",
            "TituloDataImpressaoVisualizada": null,
            "SacadoCelular": "44999958297",
            "TituloValorCobrado": "0,00",
            "TituloDataJuros": "14/10/2018 00:00:00",
            "TituloCodigoMulta": "2",
            "TituloAceite": null,
            "TituloPrazoBaixa": null,
            "TituloSacadorAvalista": "CHINA E REIS LOCAÇÃO DE MÁQUINAS LTDA",
            "TituloSacadorAvalistaEndereco": "Avenida JK 466",
            "TituloSacadorAvalistaCidade": "Nova Londrina",
            "TituloSacadorAvalistaCEP": "87970000",
            "TituloSacadorAvalistaUF": "PR",
            "TituloInscricaoSacadorAvalista": "08815635000159",
            "TituloCodBaixaDevolucao": null,
            "TituloCodigoJuros": null,
            "TituloDocEspecie": null,
            "TituloCodDesconto": null,
            "TituloCodDesconto2": null,
            "TituloCodEmissaoBloqueto": null,
            "TituloOutrasDeducoes": null,
            "TituloUsoBanco": null,
            "TituloPagamentoMinimo": "0,00",
            "TituloLocalPagamento": "PAGÁVEL PREFERENCIALMENTE NAS AGÊNCIAS DE CRÉDITO SICREDI",
            "TituloForcarFatorVencimento": null,
            "TituloInformacoesAdicionais": null,
            "TituloInstrucoes": null,
            "TituloParcela": null,
            "TituloVariacaoCarteira": null,
            "TituloCategoria": null,
            "TituloModalidade": "1",
            "TituloCodCliente": null,
            "TituloIos": null,
            "TituloCip": null,
            "TituloCodProtesto": 3,
            "CedenteAgencia": "072804",
            "CedenteAgenciaDV": null,
            "CedenteCodigoBanco": "748",
            "CedenteConta": "61233",
            "CedenteContaNumeroDV": "2",
            "CedenteCarteira": "1",
            "CedenteNumeroConvenio": "61233"
        }
    ],
    "_meta": {
        "_itens_por_pagina": 20,
        "_paginacao": {
            "_proximo": false,
            "_anterior": false
        },
        "_total": 1
    }
}
```

Preciso pegar algumas informações dai.
Estou usando o seguinte metodo:

```
private static List<PagamentoRealizado> pagamentosDoJson(String json)
        throws IOException {
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json));
    JsonObject status = reader.readObject();
    JsonObject dados = status.getJsonObject("sucesso");
    JsonArray titulosNaoConciliados = dados.getJsonArray("_dados");
    return titulosNaoConciliados
            .stream()
            .map(titulo -> {
                JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) titulo;
                String tituloNossoNumero = obj.getString("TituloNossoNumero");
                boolean pagamentoRealizado = obj.getBoolean("PagamentoRealizado");
                return new PagamentoRealizado(tituloNossoNumero, pagamentoRealizado);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Mas recebo um erro de `java.lang.NullPointerException` aqui: `JsonArray titulosNaoConciliados = dados.getJsonArray("_dados");`

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao usar `dados.getJsonArray("_dados");` você está tentando ler o `_dados` de dentro do `sucesso`, o que não faz sentido. Aliás, o nodo não se chama `sucesso` e sim `_status` e ele é uma `String` que deveria ser lida com `getString` ao invés de `getJsonObject`.

A causa do problema parece ser que você inverteu as variáveis `dados` e `status` e acabou se confundindo. Essa confusão é tipicamente criada por você ter dado nomes incorretos às variáveis e assim usar uma coisa pensando ser outra. Aliás, recomendaria chamar de `raiz` ao invés de `dados` o nodo JSON que representa o objeto lido como um todo para evitar confusão.

Logo, estas linhas:

```
JsonObject status = reader.readObject();
JsonObject dados = status.getJsonObject("sucesso");
JsonArray titulosNaoConciliados = dados.getJsonArray("_dados");
```

Deveriam ser isso:

```
JsonObject raiz = reader.readObject();
String status = raiz.getString("_status");
JsonArray titulosNaoConciliados = raiz.getJsonArray("_dados");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mais o erro persiste no _status.
org.glassfish.json.JsonStringImpl cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonObject
 at org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl.getJsonObject(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:184)

Comment: @LeandroSantos Resposta editada.

Comment: Muito bom cara deu certo obrigado.