# Converter um JSON para uma lista em Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

Estou tendo dificuldades para transformar um JSON para uma lista em Java, tentei com o GSON e com o Jackson, mas não consegui sucesso com nenhum dos dois. O meu JSON está formatado assim:

```
[[["00000000000","00000","Fulano de Souza",""],
["11111111111","111111","Sicrano da Silva",""],["22222222222","","Cilano de Tal","X"]]]
```

Essa é minha classe para o JSON:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using= Deserializador.class)
public class AlunoSGP {
    @JsonProperty("0")
    private String nomeAluno;
    @JsonProperty("1")
    private String cpfAluno;
    @JsonProperty("2")
    private String raAluno;
    @JsonProperty("3")
    private boolean bolsista;

    public AlunoSGP(String nome, String ra, String cpf, String bolsa) {
        this.nomeAluno = nome;
        this.raAluno = ra;
        this.cpfAluno = cpf;

        bolsista = "X".equals(bolsa);
    }

   //Getters e Setters
```

E meu código que deserializa o JSON está assim:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(AlunoSGP.class, new Deserializador());

    try{
        List<AlunoSGP> lstAlunos = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, AlunoSGP[].class));
        System.out.println("\nTeste lista");
        for(AlunoSGP aluno : lstAlunos){
            System.out.println(aluno.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Por último, este é meu código do `Deserializador` customizado:

```
@Override
public AlunoSGP deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      TreeNode tn = p.readValueAsTree();
      String nomeAluno;
      String raAluno;
      String cpfAluno;
      String bolsaAluno;

      if (tn.get(0) != null) {
        cpfAluno = tn.get(0).toString();
      } else {
        cpfAluno = "Erro nomeAluno";
      }

      if (tn.get(1) != null) {
        raAluno = tn.get(1).toString();
      } else {
        raAluno = "Erro nomeAluno";
      }

      if (tn.get(2) != null) {
        nomeAluno = tn.get(2).toString();
      } else {
        nomeAluno = "Erro nomeAluno";
      }

      if (tn.get(3) != null) {
        bolsaAluno = tn.get(3).toString();
      } else {
        bolsaAluno = "Erro nomeAluno";
      }

      return new AlunoSGP(nomeAluno, raAluno, cpfAluno, bolsaAluno);
}
```

Com esse código eu consigo printar os Alunos na minha lista, porém os dados estão todos `Erro nomeAluno`, ou seja, o meu deserializador está retornando `null` nas posições do JSON, estou totalmente perdido sobre o que fazer.

Comment: Até onde sei, JSON é delimitado por `{...}` e não `[...]`, além de `"terem": "valores"`.

Comment: @CypherPotato, existe a lista JSON e o objeto JSON. Um objeto JSON é delimitado por `{}` e é composto por pares de chave/valor, onde a chave é uma string e um valor é uma entidade. Uma lista JSON é delimitada por `[]` e contém diversas entidades. Uma entidade, nesse caso, pode ser um objeto, uma lista ou algum escalar (como nulo, número, string, booleano ou algum outro que eu possa ter esquecido)

Comment: @CypherPotato, para esse caso parece que o mais adequado seria produzir e consumir objetos JSON (ou lista de objetos, se puder retornar mais de um). Faz mais sentido do que mandar listas arbitrárias para cima e para baixo...

Comment: @CypherPotato Complementando o comentário do Jefferson, qualquer um dos tipos definidos pela [sintaxe do JSON](http://json.org) é considerado válido (ou seja, apenas a string `"abc"` ou o número `123`, isoladamente, também são JSON's válidos). O que acontece é que 99,999% das APIs retornam objetos (delimitados por `{}`), mas nada impede que se retorne uma lista (delimitada por `[]`), ou até mesmo uma simples string ou número... Inclusive, dependendo do caso, é até melhor. Se a API for "api.com/users/qtd_total", por que não retornar só `100` em vez de `{ "qtd_total_users": 100 }`? :-)

Comment: Provável duplicidade https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329595/ler-json-e-transformar-em-lista-em-java Aqui tem algumas respostas que podem te ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro vamos ver como é a estrutura do seu JSON (com alguns comentários explicativos):

```
[  <-- aqui temos um array
    [  <-- dentro desse array, tem outro array
           e dentro desse segundo array, temos 3 arrays
           (cada um com os dados de um aluno)
        ["00000000000", "00000", "Fulano de Souza", ""],
        ["11111111111", "111111", "Sicrano da Silva", ""],
        ["22222222222", "", "Cilano de Tal ", "X"]
    ]
]
```

Segundo a [sintaxe do JSON](http://json.org/), os colchetes `[]` delimitam um array, e seus elementos são separados por vírgulas (mas caso só tenha um elemento, não terá vírgulas, então `[1]` e `[1, 2]` são ambos arrays JSON válidos).

Ou seja, você tem um array. Dentro dele, tem somente um elemento, que é outro array. E dentro desse segundo array, você tem 3 elementos, sendo que cada um deles também é um array (cada um destes contendo os dados de um aluno).

---

Outra maneira de ver este JSON é analisar de dentro para fora. Primeiro você tem um array que representa os dados de um aluno:

```js
// este array contém os dados de um aluno
["00000000000", "00000", "Fulano de Souza", ""]
```

Você tem 3 arrays desse tipo, que seriam os dados de 3 alunos. Então sua estrutura pode ser vista da seguinte maneira:

```
[  <-- aqui temos um array
    [  <-- dentro desse array, tem outro array
           e dentro desse segundo array, temos 3 alunos
        aluno1, aluno2, aluno3
    ]
]
```

Ou seja, cada aluno é representado por um array com os dados do mesmo. Você tem um array com 3 alunos, e este array está dentro de outro array. Ou seja, você tem um array de array de alunos.

---

#### Jackson

Dito isso, uma alternativa seria ler este JSON como um array de arrays, e em seguida pegar o primeiro elemento do array lido. Com [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), ficaria assim:

```java
// um array de arrays, para corresponder à estrutura do JSON
AlunoSGP[][] array = mapper.readValue(json, AlunoSGP[][].class);

// pega o primeiro elemento do array, que é o array de alunos
List<AlunoSGP> lstAlunos = Arrays.asList(array[0]);

for (AlunoSGP aluno : lstAlunos) {
    System.out.println(aluno.toString());
}
```

Na verdade, a criação da lista é redundante, você poderia iterar diretamente pelo array:

```java
AlunoSGP[][] array = mapper.readValue(json, AlunoSGP[][].class);
for (AlunoSGP aluno : array[0]) {
    System.out.println(aluno.toString());
}
```

Outro detalhe é que no seu `Deserializador` você está retornando os valores com as aspas, então o nome fica `"Fulano"` em vez de `Fulano`. Uma alternativa para corrigir isso seria alterá-lo para percorrer os tokens do array e ir populando os dados do aluno em um loop:

```java
@Override
public AlunoSGP deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String[] values = new String[4];
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        JsonToken token = p.nextToken();
        if (JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(token) || token == null) {
            break;
        }
        values[i++] = p.getValueAsString();
    }
    return new AlunoSGP(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
}
```

Aqui não foram incluídas validações quanto ao conteúdo e tamanho do array - ele assume que sempre vai ter 4 elementos. Você pode incluir as validações, caso ache necessário.

---

#### `Gson`

Com [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson), a lógica é a mesma: leia o JSON como um array de array de alunos.

Primeiro você cria um [`com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html), que vai transformar cada array em um aluno:

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class AlunoDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<AlunoSGP> {
    @Override
    public AlunoSGP deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type member, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
        if (array.size() != 4) {
            // array não tem 4 posições, não dá para criar aluno
            throw new JsonParseException("Faltam dados do aluno");
        }
        // cria o aluno, usando as informações do array
        return new AlunoSGP(array.get(0).getAsString(), array.get(1).getAsString(),
                            array.get(2).getAsString(), array.get(3).getAsString());
    }
}
```

Depois, basta ler o JSON como um array de array de alunos:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                // registrar o JsonDeserializer de alunos
                .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(AlunoSGP.class, new AlunoDeserializer())
                .create();
// ler o JSON como um array de array de alunos
AlunoSGP[][] arrayDeArrayDeAlunos = gson.fromJson(json, AlunoSGP[][].class);
for (AlunoSGP aluno : arrayDeArrayDeAlunos[0]) {
    System.out.println(aluno.toString());
}
```

---

<sup>Por fim, algo que não está diretamente relacionado ao problema. Se você tem uma classe chamada `AlunoSGP`, é meio redundante que os campos se chamem `nomeAluno`, `cpfAluno`, etc. Eles poderiam se chamar apenas `nome` e `cpf`, pois já está subentendido que esses são dados do aluno.</sup>

Comment: Cara, acabei de implementar aqui e funcionou, muito obrigado, explicou muito bem, parabéns!

Answer (score 1):

Ola,

Talvez você possa criar o seu json assim

```
{
   "alunos":[
      {
         "nomeAluno":"00000000000",
         "cpfAluno":"00000",
         "raAluno":"Fulano de Souza",
         "bolsista":""
      },
      {
         "nomeAluno":"00000000000",
         "cpfAluno":"00000",
         "raAluno":"Fulano de Souza",
         "bolsista":""
      }
   ]
}
```

Ai as suas classes para deserialização ficariam parecida com isso

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"nomeAluno",
"cpfAluno",
"raAluno",
"bolsista"
})
public class Aluno {

@JsonProperty("nomeAluno")
private String nomeAluno;
@JsonProperty("cpfAluno")
private String cpfAluno;
@JsonProperty("raAluno")
private String raAluno;
@JsonProperty("bolsista")
private String bolsista;

@JsonProperty("nomeAluno")
public String getNomeAluno() {
return nomeAluno;
}

@JsonProperty("nomeAluno")
public void setNomeAluno(String nomeAluno) {
this.nomeAluno = nomeAluno;
}

@JsonProperty("cpfAluno")
public String getCpfAluno() {
return cpfAluno;
}

@JsonProperty("cpfAluno")
public void setCpfAluno(String cpfAluno) {
this.cpfAluno = cpfAluno;
}

@JsonProperty("raAluno")
public String getRaAluno() {
return raAluno;
}

@JsonProperty("raAluno")
public void setRaAluno(String raAluno) {
this.raAluno = raAluno;
}

@JsonProperty("bolsista")
public String getBolsista() {
return bolsista;
}

@JsonProperty("bolsista")
public void setBolsista(String bolsista) {
this.bolsista = bolsista;
}

}
```

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"alunos"
})
public class Alunos {

@JsonProperty("alunos")
private List<Aluno> alunos = null;

@JsonProperty("alunos")
public List<Aluno> getAlunos() {
return alunos;
}

@JsonProperty("alunos")
public void setAlunos(List<Aluno> alunos) {
this.alunos = alunos;
}

}
```

Um site muito util que pode ajudar você a gerar a classe a partir do JSON por exemplo é este http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Você pode usar este site https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ também para validar se o seu JSON está valido

Comment: só complementando, os colchetes são usados para indicar uma lista no JSON

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, acabei esquecendo de mencionar que não consigo mudar o JSON, não tenho acesso ao código que formata ele, então tenho que trabalhar com ele assim mesmo

Comment: Olá @GabrielSandoli creio que a sua solução seja manipular o json usando as classes de manipulação de String no java, procure por StringBuilder, para que você manipule o JSON depois de recebe-lo com o StringBuilder e seus métodos você pode apagar alguns colchetes do JSON e até inserir texto dinamicamente, assim você conseguirá formatar o JSON para um padrão adequado.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada @BrendonIwata, obrigado!

Comment: @BrendonIwata Não precisa manipular a string. O JSON que ele recebe é válido (só tem uma estrutura meio "estranha", pois não vejo motivo pra terem feito um array dentro de outro) mas de qualquer forma é perfeitamente possível lê-lo com as bibliotecas de JSON - como eu fiz na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405280/112052), por exemplo :-)

Answer (score 0):

Usando o Gson eu consegui aqui, você pode fazer assim

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Object object = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(filePath), Object.class);
```

Onde filepath é o caminho onde está o seu arquivo json

Ai você pode converter este Object para uma lista assim

```
List lista = Arrays.asList(object);
```

para percorrer a lista você pode fazer assim

```
Iterator it = lista.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            List inner = (List) it.next();
            Iterator it2 = inner.iterator();
            while (it2.hasNext()) {
                List inner2 = (List) it2.next();
                for (Object obj : inner2) {
                    System.out.println(obj);
                }

            }
        }
```